# ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S25') dtype('S25') dtype('S25')

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, multiplication

i am trying to run a script that would multiply two multi dimensional arrays using numpy, i have tried the following but it gives me an error saying

"TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S25') dtype('S25') dtype('S25')"

```
import numpy as np
alldata = [['a' '1' '2' '2'] ['3.0' '3.0' '4.0' '3.0']['2.0' '2.0' '2.0' '4.0']]
a = np.array(alldata)
newa = a[1]
newb = a[2]
result = np.multiply(newa,newb)
```

Comment: You can't multiply strings.

Comment: That `alldata` line is not valid Python.  Lists require commas.  And before trying to `multiply` make sure `newa` and `newb` are valid arrays of numbers.